# Navigation property returns NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to print Person.bank1.Name for every Person in Index View but is always NULL. I'm using Code first. In database tables everything is OK.

Context is:

```
public class PersonContext : DbContext
{
    public PersonContext()
        : base("name=PersonContext")
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Bank> banks { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Person> person { get; set; }
}
```

Person Model

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int bank { get; set; }
    public virtual Bank bank1 { get; set;}
}
```

Bank Model:

```
public class Bank
{
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Person> person { get; set; }
}
```

Persons Controller Index and Create Methods:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var person = db.person.Include(c => c.bank1);
        return View(person.ToList());
    }

   // GET: Persons/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.BankList = new SelectList(db.banks, "id", "name");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Persons/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,bank")] Person person)
    {
        ViewBag.BankList = new SelectList(db.banks, "id", "name");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.person.Add(person);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(person);
    }
```

Comment: Did you create foreign key for person to bank in database or in 'OnModelCreating' function in your context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your bank int property as a foreign key in your Person Class-

```
[ForeignKey("Bank1")]
public int bank { get; set; }
```

This should do the trick.